# Unity3d: Loading ScriptableObject from a dll

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I have 2 projects,
The first project is standalone app, where I'm creating an assetbundle
with a couple of prefabs and with a scriptable object that contains
some setting for my app.(I have around 30 standalone apps and each one
have its own assetbundle).

The second project is a store app(like Kindle), that users can purchase my apps and use them inside it, instead of purchasing through the app store or google play.

So for me to manage the code more easily, I've created a dll from my first project.

So far so good.

When I'm trying to load the scriptable object in my second project(it's inside a dll now), I'm getting Null Reference exception,
debbuging it for its names show me that the assetbundle contain the setting file.

This is my scriptable object:

```
 public class BookOnLoadSettings : ScriptableObject {

    public string bookName = "";

    public int numberOfPages;
    public bool isMultiResoluion = false;
    public bool UsePageSelectionPanel = false;

    public BookInnerPagesTransition.BookDirectionType
        BookDirection = BookInnerPagesTransition.BookDirectionType.Rtl;
    public ScreenOrientation Orientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
    public InnerPagesUIButtonsSettings innerPagesUIButtonsSettings;
    public AudioClip soundTrackClip;
    public float SoundtrackVolum = 0.5f;


}
```

and this is the code where I get a null exception:

```
private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), ""))
        {
            var fileName = "myBook.hdd";
            var path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, fileName);
            Debug.Log(path);
            StartCoroutine(_run(path));

        }
    }

 private IEnumerator _run(string  path)
    {
        var request = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(path);
        yield return request;
        var assetBundle = request.assetBundle;
        if (assetBundle == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("_assetBundle is null");

        }

        foreach (var assetName in assetBundle.GetAllAssetNames())
        {
            Debug.Log("assetName: "+assetName);
            var obj = assetBundle.LoadAsset(assetName);
            Debug.Log(obj.GetType().Name);
        }

        //

        BookOnLoadSettings settings = assetBundle.LoadAsset<BookOnLoadSettings>(
            "onloadsettings.asset" 
        );


        Debug.Log("is settings null: "+(settings == null).ToString());


        yield return 0;
    }
```

so it prints the asset name inside the assetbundle,
but fail to load it, while other assets inside the assetbundle
load as expected.
This problem doesn't occur in my first project where my scriptable object
isn't inside a dll.

So what am I doing wrong ? :)

Thanks.

Comment: I've sent a bug report to unity, and they have confirmed that there is a bug.     they said that this bug have a fix in 2018.2 version that is currently in internal alpha.